# Can we have use an external payment processor or do we have to use in-app billing in Google Playstore?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, billing, in-app-subscription

we are developing an app that links people together. 
For every successful 'match' we deduct a credit. People pay for credits or purchase a subscription.

Since the connection is digital we have to use in-app purchases in both Google and Apple markets and they take a cut of 30%.
Obviously we think this is rather steep and want to see if we can use alternatives.

Maybe some of you know more about this and can help us out answering the following questions:

1. How can Spotify sell its subscriptions through 3rd party PSP on Android?? Has it got to do with the fact that Google policy states:

> Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app
>   itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).

Would that mean that if users use the credits via our website to do the same thing as in the app, then we could use our own payment methods?

2. We understand Apple is very strict on this matter. However, if we approach our customers **outside the app** to subscribe through our website....would we get away with this??
3. Google policy states:

> In-app virtual currencies must only be used within the app where they
>   were first purchased.

**

How should we interpret this? Does it mean that people who buy credits in the app cannot use the credits on another device or via our webbrowser?

If you have any tips or experience on this...please share.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but instead about payment policies.

Comment: Why is it off-topic? More people on Stack have questions about these matters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It has to do with what we need to program (IAP/3rd party). See more questions about these policies on Stack. But could you otherwise direct me to another forum? Happy X-mas